# C++ -- Win32 API, GUI stuff

Tags: c++, winapi, user-interface, window

I've been messing with Win32 API for abit, and I've got a question regarding the GUI functions.

How does one handle user input that is not managed through popup windows? I've been reading http://www.winprog.org/ but right when the interesting features comes -- lesson9 -- it becomes more abstract and I'm not sure how to do it.
Basically what I am after is the user to write input in two windows and then press a button to send a message that the content of the input is to be processed. 
I think the input windows would be some EDIT-class windows and the input BUTTON-class but that's about it.

Any ideas? I'm sure it's simple, it's just makes me want to rip my hair of in native code :p

Cheers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're correct, you want and `EDIT` control which is more commonly known as a `TextBox` and a `BUTTON` class which is a command button.

To get the the input the Button will send a `WM_COMMAND` message to its parent window with a `BN_CLICKED` in the `wParam` high word. You can identify the particular button from the `hWnd` you get in that message.

After that you'll need to post a `WM_GETTEXT` to the edit control to retrieve the users input.

This is all from memory so I highly recommend looking up the msdn pages before you code.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I follow 100%. Yes, you would use EDIT and BUTTON-class controls for that. Where are you getting stuck?